# How can I prevent read-only users from creating collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I created a read-only user in MongoDB using the following query:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
    user: "user1",
    pwd: "user123",
    roles: [{
        role: "read",
        db: "dbTest"
    }],
    
     mechanisms:[  
  "SCRAM-SHA-1"
 ]
})
```

However, after logging in as that read-only user, I unexpectedly was still able to create collections and perform inserts.

Comment: Did you exited/logged out after creating it??

Comment: yes i logged out. and actually i also try to logging with new connection using robo 3T

Comment: Did you also enable access control in your `mongod` configuration? The documentation includes a tutorial with all steps: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#re-start-the-mongodb-instance-with-access-control.